# When to use single quotes in an SQL statement?

Tags: sql, sqlite, quotes

I know that I should use it when I deal with data of TEXT type (and I guess the ones that fall back to TEXT), but is it the only case?

Example:

```
UPDATE names SET name='Mike' WHERE id=3
```

I'm writing an SQL query auto generation in C++, so I want to make sure I don't miss cases, when I have to add quotes.

Comment: You need to wrap strings in quotes. Numerics/decimals etc should not be in quotes but oftentimes you can put them in quotes and they will be implicity converted - it depends what version of SQL you are using.

Comment: @Charleh does it mean that "id='3'" will converted to "id=3". Is that what you mean?

Comment: @rightaway717: Yes, in many SQL DBMS, if the type of column `id` is INTEGER but you pass `'3'` as a value to be compared, that may be accepted and the conversion done at some point in the statement preparation or execution.  Other DBMS will simply give you a mismatched type error from the start.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Single quotes (`'`) denote textual data, as you noted (e.g., `'Mike'` in your example). Numeric data (e.g., `3` in your example), object (table, column, etc) names and syntactic elements (e.g., `update`, `set`, `where`) should not be wrapped in quotes.

Answer (score 1):

The single quote is the delimiter for the string. It lets the parser know where the string starts and where it ends as well as that is is a string. You will find that sometimes you get away with a double quote too.

The only way to be certain you don't miss any cases would be to escape the input, otherwise this will be vulnerable to abuse when somehow a single quote ends up in in the text.